# Expo sending OTA updates

Tags: react-native, expo

I had no idea Expo did this. But I created a small office application and working on an update. While working on the update, I did

```
 expo publish
```

So that the team I'm working with could use the Expo and see the route I'm going. And it updated the production app throughout the company.

in my App.json file

```
"updates": {
      "enabled": false,
      "checkAutomatically": "ON_LOAD",
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
```

I want to still be able to publish the app, without it updating the production app.

how do I do that when I publish?

Comment: Look at [this](https://docs.expo.io/guides/configuring-ota-updates/).

Answer (score 2):

Check out Expo [release channels](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/release-channels/).

When you build your standalone apps to iOS or Android it binds that build to whatever release channel was specified. It is set to `default` channel by default.

**You can build your apps to a specific channel by running:**

`expo build:ios --release-channel <your-channel>`

`expo build:android --release-channel <your-channel>`

**Then, when you want to publish to that release channel you do so by running:**

`expo publish --release-channel <your-channel>`